# Lightbox is not working in my new Blogger template

Tags: blogger, lightbox

I am useing new Blogger template and the Lightbox for opening the pictures is not working.
https://xn--80aerbwvhdn.blogspot.com/2019/02/rar.html

Answer (score 0):

As first step you have to activate this option in blogger platform settings. If this is activated, the second one you have to see is for jQuery conflicts...